# How to stop android from killing my daemons

Tags: android, out-of-memory

My Android "smart TV box" has a disk attached where I have a small Debian distribution installed running various server processes (ntp, mpd, lighttpd, ...).  Problem is, even though I have plenty of swap space, some of my daemons tend to "die" when there's a lot of activity (i.e. when the machine swaps a bit more).  I do not know for a fact what is the root cause, but it sounds like it might be some kind of Android OOM system deciding that it's better to kill those processes (presumably because it is tuned on the assumption that there is no swap).

How can I verify that this is indeed the case?

If it is the case, hwo can I stop the kernel from killing processes even when there's still plenty of space in the swap?

Comment: Android reserves the right to kill any service at any time.  It also sets a per app memory limit, and will not let an app go over it even if you have gigs of ram left.  So you need to code your services assuming they can be killed for no reason at any time.  One trick is to make your service's onCreate call startService on itself-  for some reason Android tends to kill everything every 8 hours or so, this gets around that problem (although if you were doing something when it was killed that may be lost).

Comment: These are true native Linux daemons that "die", and not SDK apps?

Comment: Right, these are Debian daemons that know nothing about Android.

Comment: Hmmm... I wasn't aware that Android would terminate non-SDK apps this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak out of memory killer writing to `/sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters`. Being a kernel killer I don't think it discriminates between android or native processes, but I may be wrong.

More detailed information can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=622666)

Comment: I added `echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 >/sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree` to the startup scripts, and the problem is gone, thank you.